# Unexpected field in Mysql fetch data

Tags: mysql

I have a query in which the data is lifted from the database. 
Eg: I have Category as a field which has values like Doctors, Pathologists etc which is taken from the database.

```
 Category
 --------
 Doctors
 Pathologists
 Pediatrics/Child Specialist --->> Unwanted data
```

The problem is there is a data(value) in 'Category' field which is unexpectedly showing in the list which is not in my database. I even tried to drop the table entirely and reload it but that field is still showing.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Additional Info

```
function  getTierCategory()
{
echo "</br>";
$result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT Category FROM doctors order by Category asc") 
or die(mysql_error());

  while($tier = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) 

    {
       echo '<option value="'.$tier['Category'].'">'.$tier['Category'].'</option>';
    }

}
```

I have tried renaming the field but how can I if this value is not even in my database.

My Database looks like

```
Category | Qualification | State  | District
--------------------------------------------
```

and so on

Comment: What's the name of the field?  Can you also supply the query?

Comment: We need more information, and more code.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to your database in PHPmyadmin or something like that and check results of your mysql query.

In some complex queries you can receive redundant fields (on example indexes when you have counting variable in PHP) or NULL values.

mysql_fetch_array() returns results in two ways:

- number indexed array ($array[0] etc)
- associative array ($array['field_name'] etc)

Try with mysql_fetch_assoc or mysql_fetch_row instead. Also PDO_MYSQL API is recommended to use for MySQL querying. It has more convenient form.

Comment: @user501582: It is hard to say without any real data and empirical tests.